# How to turn a Linux system into dual boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, filesystems, mount

I have a computer with two storage devices in it. I want to have two Linux systems in it, and I want them to be based on the same installation. One will live in a ext4 filesystem and the other will live in a btrfs filesystem. Once I start to use them of course they will start to diverge.

What I've done so far:

- Install Linux (Ubuntu 21.04) in a volume (partition) on device B. Install other things I need.
- Create a btrfs filesystem in a volume (partition) on device A.
- Mount filesystem on device A.
- Copy everything on device B to device A using `rsync -avP --numeric-ids --exclude='/dev' --exclude='/proc' --exclude='/sys'`.
- Create a different file on the desktop of each system so once I've re-booted I know which system booted into.
- Edit `/etc/fstab` of the system on device A so it mounts the correct filesystem when booting.
- Run `update-grub`as root.
- Reboot and select the system A in the boot menu.

Once I've rebooted I notice that the system which booted is the original one. Ext4 on device B.

I've tried both in styles in fstab: UUID and /dev/sdXX

I'm sure I'm missing a step or two, but I can't figure out what/which.
What am I missing or doing wrong? Why isn't fstab not honored?

Comment: fstab is not responsible for the mounting of `/` (the "real root"). `update-grub` / `grub-mkconfig` alone will not discover the copy AFAIK/IIRC. You either need to write a custom entry or install os-prober (perhaps only the former will work if you want them to share kernel(s) / `/boot` filesystem). Anyway, the key is to get a new entry created with a different `root=` boot parameter. (With that said, sometimes/often the fstab will includes an entry for `/`, for the purpose of e.g. ro->rw remounting, so you do need to check if it needs updating/correction.)

Comment: Hi @TomYan, thanks for your comment. I have successfully runned update-grub as root and it did detect the copied system and it has been added to grub menu. My problem is that whatever I select from the grub entry in the boot menu I end up in the original system.

Comment: Paste your grub.cfg. There's a chance that while the two entries load kernel from different partition, the `root=` they use are the same.

Comment: I've pasted here: https://pastebin.com/sbyxnS5J If it ended up with both entries pointing to the same device/volume does it mean update-grub has a bug? or is it just that I'm missing something?

Comment: Well, not exactly a bug. It's just something not supposed to work. Think of this: how would it know both of the partitions consists of a root filesystem? It can at best locate two sets of kernel(s) / initramfs(es), but then there's no guarantee that the filesystems that contain them are root filesystems (they can be in separate partition(s) for `/boot`. So it will use the current `/` for `root=` of both sets of entries. (Therefore, I'm not entirely sure if even os-prober can help. Perhaps it does it with some best-bet heuristics whatsoever. So your only option might be a custom entry.)

Comment: Actually, things would be even trickier once you booted to the copy, as `update-grub` there won't update the grub.cfg that would actually be used, because you aren't sharing `/boot`. I don't know if there's a nice way of avoiding `update-grub` entirely in Ubuntu and just maintain grub.cfg yourself manually. The best way to do it in Arch is to re-install grub with `--boot-directory` set to the mountpoint of a seperate but shared partition (e.g. the EFI system partition: `/boot/efi`).

Comment: Another option is to use different sets of grub for them, i.e. choose with the UEFI boot menu. Install grub properly on the drive of the copy for that.

Comment: Could I fix it following some of the steps mentioned here? https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/139846 I mean, if I can boot the copied system I will be satisfied for now.

Comment: Well, that's more or less the UEFI boot menu approach, chroot to reinstall grub for the copy. (There's a choice to make as well: share ESP or not.) But blindly following it won't work. (It's written for BIOS/legacy installation.)

Comment: If you want it to work *for now*, just change the UUIDs after `root=UUID=` of the entries (or main entry) of the copy in the grub.cfg on the original drive. The effort will be overwritten once `update-grub` is run, so you need to do that every time.

Comment: Try this: https://paste.debian.net/plain/1198514

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124602/discussion-between-falk-and-tom-yan).

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix it.

Steps were almost the same.

- create partition table again.
- create a small 512MB fat32 volume on filesystem A for UEFI, /dev/sda1, set the right flags.
- create system filesystem as btrfs /dev/sda2.
- mount filesystem /dev/sda2 on `/mnt` instead of `/media/...`
- call rsync again, adding the `--exclude='/mnt'` parameter. This is important to avoid copying the same content recursively over and over again.
- call `blkid` and noted the UUIDs of the two new partitions.
- edit `/mnt/etc/fstab` in order to put the correct UUIDs, and change the mount options for btrfs of course.
- call `update-grub`. This changes the boot options on device B adding the system on device A as a menu entry.
- call `grub-install --efi-directory /boot/efi/`. This installs boot options on UEFI partition on device B.
- Reboot the system.
- Select boot entry which shows `/dev/sda2`.
- Make sure the correct system booted. Eg, look for a specific file, run mount, whatever.
- run `update-grub` again, this time it acts on device A.
- run `grub-install --efi-directory /boot/efi/` also acts on device A.
- Reboot and tell BIOS/UEFI to boot device A.

I think now it should work.

Comment: Actually there's the switch `-x` in rsync, save you all the `--exclude`s, especially handy if you use a single partition/filesystem for an installation (ESP not included).

Comment: Your steps don't seem to make sense. Reinstalling grub on the original ESP doesn't magically make the grub entries for the copy correct. (And it was even done after `update-grub`.) What you should do is install grub on the new ESP and `update-grub` after chrooting to `/mnt` (with `/mnt/boot/efi` mounted).

Comment: `grub-install` can be done either inside or outside chroot. If outside, the command would be `grub-install --efi-directory /mnt/boot/efi --boot-directory /mnt/boot`. `update-grub` has to be done inside chroot though.

Comment: I think that update-grub is smart enough to detect that there are 2 operating systems present. I have made so many things that I not 100% sure which were the important ones. I will try to replicate it with a virtual machine.

Comment: The thing is, where comes your original question then? And how did it go away? Though I've been too far away from grub.cfg generation anyway. With a rolling release there's no reason at all for me not to write the grub.cfg myself. After a second thought perhaps it can determine the `/` for each set of kernel(s), since you are not using separate a `/boot` partition for any of them. In that case you might want to eliminate grub completely on either of them to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you want to stick with using UEFI boot menu, perhaps you should get rid of os-prober on both them.

Comment: I have still a lot to learn about the boot process. For now I'll stick to grub. Of course only one grub is needed. I think it's awesome how many low level things you can do in Linux.